# Return back to previous line in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file where I want to write values from following three lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,3,2]
c = [7,8,9]
```

in format:

```
a-b
c
```

so the arrangement in text file would look like:

```
1-4   2-3   3-2  
7     8     9
```

I have tried following

`for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
     ofile.write("p%s-%s\n%s\t" %(x,y,z))`

But output in text file is arranged like this:

```
1-4
7     2-3
8     3-2
9
```

Any suggestions on how to return to first line and arrange text as needed would be appreciative.

Comment: Write the whole first line, *then* the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip `a` and `b` on their own, write that line, then write `c` on the next:

```
ofile.write('\t'.join(['{}-{}'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(a, b)]) + '\n')
ofile.write('\t'.join(map(str, c)) + '\n')
```

This uses [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to put tabs between the values on a line.

It'd be easier to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to take care of turning values into strings and to write tabs and line separators:

```
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerow(['{}-{}'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(a b)])
writer.writerow(c)
```

Comment: Or replace `'{}-{}'.format(*pair)` with `'%s-%s' % pair`.

Comment: @WKPlus: sure, but I prefer to teach the more powerful and newer `str.format()` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: One side question -- if I have another list 'd' which has 9 values and I want to place every 3 values from it underneath each column sequentially to get them in 3 rows. How to do it?

Comment: @Ibe: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443); split into chunks, pass chunks to `writerows()`.